# Thermodynamics question - Why does my apartment get colder when the weather gets warmer?

Tags: thermodynamics, weather, building-physics

I'm in North Dakota, and over the last several years, I've noticed a trend. Whenever we have a cold snap (the weather gets below 0 degrees F), my apartment stays relatively warm (68-70 degrees F). But when the cold snap ends (the temperature goes back up to 5-10 degrees F, or even higher), the temperature in the apartment drops to 54-57 degrees F. (Neither of these apartment states is impacted by fiddling with the thermostat, and this phenomenon has occurred in multiple apartments that I've lived in.)

Is there a scientific explanation for this pattern?

Comment: Does your apartment have central heating?

Comment: I think so. I know the building has a boiler of some kind, but I don't know if it's just for hot water or if it's also for heating the building.

Comment: In the winter your neighbours are heating up the walls, while in the summer they don't.

Comment: My question is not about when it's summer. It's about when the cold snap ends. The weather outside is still 9 degrees Fahrenheit. While that's warmer than it was yesterday, I don't think my neighbors are turning off their heat just yet.

Comment: In my apartment there is a person responsible for turning on and off the times of heating of the building, which he reduces when the outside temperature gets some degrees hotter. and puts back when it gets colder outside. This would reproduce your effect.